# Issue login after set a new shell

Tags: 14.04, unity, session

Yesterday I changed my shell to ZSH with framework Oh-My-ZSH and now when I try to log into my session, a console is displayed quickly and it returns to the screen session.

I try to remove the `.Xauthority` and to reinstall `lightdm`, but it didn't fix the issue.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Find the absolute path of `zsh` by:

```
type -p zsh
```

The add the absolute path of `zsh` to `/etc/shells`, and read `man shells`.

`/etc/shells` is a list of "valid" login shells. On my Ubuntu 14.04.5, `/etc/shells` doesn't contain `zsh`.

Comment: Absolute path of zsh is /usr/bin/zsh, but my /etc/shells already have /usr/bin/zsh and /bin/zsh

Comment: Then your `zsh` exits/fails right away. Hide or simplify or instrument your `.profile`-like  initialization files (see `man zsh`)

Comment: Finally with your way of thinking, I found that it's my `.bashrc` which cause that issue, so I copied an other `.bashrc` with an other working ubuntu and now it works, thk u for helping me